# How to use SOCKS in Java?

Tags: java, http, proxy, socks

I use 100% working socks and I can't connect through my application.

        `SocketAddress proxyAddr = new InetSocketAddress("1.1.1.1", 12345);
        Proxy pr = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.SOCKS, proxyAddr);`

```
    try
    {
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection(pr);
        con.setConnectTimeout(proxyTimeout * 1000);
        con.setReadTimeout(proxyTimeout * 1000);
        con.connect();

        System.out.println(con.usingProxy());
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
        Logger.getLogger(Enter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

So what am I doing wrong? If I'll use HTTP with some HTTP proxy all is working but not with SOCKS.

Comment: What error message do you get? *How* does this code fail to work?

Also, are you using a SOCKS4 or SOCKS5 proxy

Comment: I tried to use both of SOCKS4 and SOCKS5. This is the error message: http://pastebin.com/xFB2qZQs But! Socks is 100% woking (socks5 here is).

Comment: Where i can get SOCKS5 library for android??
i want to use it also..

Answer (score 27):

It's really easy. You just need to set the relevant System Properties and just get on with your regular HttpConnection.

```
System.getProperties().put( "proxySet", "true" );
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyHost", "127.0.0.1" );
System.getProperties().put( "socksProxyPort", "1234" );
```

Comment: These are correct but what to do in case I need to use multi threads and I need to have many Proxies per time ? 
For example I found socks proxy which works fine in IE as SOCKS (and does not wotk as HTTP and other protocols) but when I use it in Java this does not work for v4 and for 5 ! That seems like hug suck in Java

Comment: It's worth to mention that Java will ignore the SOCKS5 settings unless proxyset is set. This is not necessary for using an HTTP proxy.

Answer (score 9):

Inform the "socksProxyHost" and "socksProxyPort" VM arguments.

e.g.

```
java -DsocksProxyHost=127.0.0.1 -DsocksProxyPort=8080 org.example.Main
```

Answer (score 2):

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/net/www/http/HttpClient.java/?v=source

Deep down, HttpClient is used in HttpURLConnection.

```
if ((proxy != null) && (proxy.type() == Proxy.Type.HTTP)) {
   sun.net.www.URLConnection.setProxiedHost(host);
   privilegedOpenServer((InetSocketAddress) proxy.address());
   usingProxy = true;
   return;
} else {
   // make direct connection
   openServer(host, port);
   usingProxy = false;
   return;
}
```

On line 476, you can see that the only acceptable proxy is an HTTP proxy. It makes a direct connection otherwise.

Weirdly there's is no support for SOCKS proxy using HttpURLConnection. Even worse, the code doesn't even t using an unsupported proxy and just ignores the proxy!

Why there isn't any support for SOCKS proxies after at least 10 years of this class' existence cannot be explained.

Answer (score 1):

Or this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64649010/5352325

If you know which URIs need to go to proxy, you can also use the low layer ProxySelector: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html where for each Socket connection that is made, you can decide what proxies are to be used.

It looks something like this:

```
public class MyProxySelector extends ProxySelector {
        ...

        public java.util.List<Proxy> select(URI uri) {
        ...
          if (uri is what I need) {
             return list of my Proxies
          }
        ...
        }
        ...
}
```

Then you make use of your selector:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        MyProxySelector ps = new MyProxySelector(ProxySelector.getDefault());
        ProxySelector.setDefault(ps);
        // rest of the application
}
```